# Проблема в шаблоне Blogger (script expr:scr)

Tags: шаблоны

Всем привет. Связался с шаблоном BLoggerA. Наткнулся на исходник виджета, который выводит "Похожие сообщения". Решил поковырять, проверить. Из-за чего-то не происходит вызов функции, которая возвращается в ответе с аргументом json-данных, выглядит сие обращение вот так: `

---

```
<script expr:src='/feeds/posts/summary/?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=results_labels&amp;max-results=6' type='text/javascript' />
```

---

По идее blogger должен был на месте этого вызова создать исходник вида и соответственно он потом нормально бы отработал в интерпретаторе

---

`<script type='text/javascript'> results_labels({"":"", "":""}); </script>`

---

но ничего не происходит, что-то пошло не так в его вселенной.  В этом вызове функции, парсятся данные и распихиваются по массивам для удобства..картинки, ссылки и др.. Следом еще вызываются две функции , где происходит формирование html-объектов и наполнение их данными с выводом в DOM:

---

```
<script type='text/javascript'> removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs(); printRelatedLabels_thumbs(&quot;&lt;data:post.url/&gt;&quot;);</script>
```

---

В чем может быть дело? На крайняк я уже Ajax-ом подгрузил те данные и переписал вывод в документ но то так..запасной случай. Хотелось бы чтобы вариант Bloggera  срабатывал.